# How to draw multiple lines in chart.js

Tags: java, json, charts, chart.js

I am using java for providing data in JSON format to chart.js, 
  Here this the java code.

```
    JSONObject json_in = new JSONObject();
     json_in.put("subject_name", rs.getString("subjectName"));
     json_in.put("max_marks", rs.getString("MaxMarks"));
     json_in.put("obtained_marks", rs.getString("marks"));
     json_arr.add(json_in);
```

Here is the chart.js

```
$("#admin_analytic_exam").on("submit", function(event){  
       event.preventDefault();  
         $.ajax({  
                 url:"admin_analytic_exam",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:$('#admin_analytic_exam').serialize(),  
                 beforeSend:function(){  
                      $('#showload').show();  
                 },  
                 success:function(graph_data){
                        // alert(data); 
                      $('#showload').hide();
                     $('#chart_block').show();

                      var subject_name = [];
                      var obtained_marks = [];
                      var max_marks = [];

                      var keys = Object.keys(graph_data);
                        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
                        {
                            var key = keys[i];
                            subject_name.push(graph_data[i].subject_name);
                            //console.log(key +" " +subject_name); 
                            obtained_marks.push(graph_data[i].obtained_marks);
                             max_marks.push(graph_data[i].max_marks);
                        }
                      console.log(subject_name);  
                      exit();
                     for(var i in graph_data){
                          subject_name.push(graph_data[i].subject_name);
                          obtained_marks.push(graph_data[i].obtained_marks);
                          label.push(graph_data[i].label);
                    }

                    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartdata,
                            options: {
                                        scales: {
                                            xAxes: [{
                                                    scaleLabel: {
                                                      display: true,
                                                      labelString: 'Subject'
                                                    }
                                                  }],
                                            yAxes: [{
                                                ticks: {
                                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                                    //stepSize: 0.5,
                                                    //suggestedMin: 0,
                                                    suggestedMax: max_marks[0]
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }
        });  
                 }  
            });
  });
```

I want to draw multiple lines dynamically. How to fetch data from database in json format to chat.js. The lines will be more than one.

Here is the JSON format which i am using

`[
{
"pointBackgroundColor":"rgba(184,184,184,1)",
"backgroundColor":"rgba(184, 184, 184, 0.2)",
"borderColor":"'rgba(184, 184, 184, 1)",
"data":"50",
"subject_Name":"CDX",
"label":"Test",
"type":"line"
},
{
"pointBackgroundColor":"rgba(184,184,184,1)",
"backgroundColor":"rgba(184, 184, 184, 0.2)",
"borderColor":"'rgba(184, 184, 184, 1)",
"data":"42",
"subject_Name":"ISM",
"label":"Test",
"type":"line"
},
{
"pointBackgroundColor":"rgba(184,184,184,1)",
"backgroundColor":"rgba(184, 184, 184, 0.2)",
"borderColor":"'rgba(184, 184, 184, 1)",
"data":"23",
"subject_Name":"DSA",
"label":"Test",
"type":"line"
}`

Comment: yep, use arrays.  data = { labels: [], datasets: [] };

Comment: Thanks , How to get data in js and how to iterate it for multiples line.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepare the given `JSON` format using `JSON` predefine functions or you can modify `JSON` by converting it to `String`.
`String string = json_obj.toString();`
You can append, remove and replace `{} []` and also add double quotes `\"` as well according to your requirement. When you have done your editing check your `JSON` format on [JSON Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr)